# How to get data from a CSV file and put into PostgreSQL database as json object using python?

Tags: json, postgresql, python-2.7

I am working on Python with PostgreSQL.

I need to get some data from a CSV file and need to put all the data as JSON in PostgreSQL.

Please help me, I am getting no way to solve it.

Comment: What did you try till now?

Comment: @Houari i am able to convert the CSV file into dict using following command:-

`csvfile = open('/root/Desktop/test.csv', 'r')
        reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile)`

But when i do `obj = json.dumps(reader)`, it is throwing an error.
So, i need to convert this reader object data into json and need to put it into postgresql db.

Comment: "it is throwing error". .... and the error is?